# C# Windows form : Sort a datagridview, then another datagriview will be sorted with corresponding order

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a class like this:

```
public class Customer  
    {  
        /// <summary>  
        /// Name of customer  
        /// </summary>  
        public string Name { get; set; }  

        /// <summary>  
        /// Sex of customer  
        /// </summary>  
        public bool Sex { get; set; }  

        /// <summary>  
        /// List of favourite foods
        /// </summary>  
        public List<string> FavouriteFoods { get; set; }  
    }
```

And I have 2 datagridviews:
dgvCustomerInfo will display Name and Sex of Customer
Another one, dgvFavouriteFoods will display first 4 favourite foods of Customer.

[These are my 2 datagridviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xvdd.png)
I want to click on any header of dgvFavouriteFoods, dgvFavouriteFoods will be sorted and dgvCustomerInfo will be also sorted with corresponding order.
Example:
Andrew likes Pizza, Hot dog, , Noodle, Chicken.
Sander likes Rice, Pork, Beef, Chicken.
When I click header of dgvFavouriteFoods, dgvFavouriteFoods is sorted, and dgvCustomerInfo should be sorted with corresponding order to let me know that
Andrew likes Pizza, Hot dog, , Noodle, Chicken.
Sander likes Rice, Pork, Beef, Chicken.

Could you please give me a solution?

This is my code to add customer to these 2 datagridviews:

```
        void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            // Add infor of customer to dgvCustomerInfo
            int rowIndexCustomerInfo = dgvCustomerInfo.Rows.Add();
            dgvCustomerInfo.Rows[rowIndexCustomerInfo].Cells[0].Value = customer.Name;
            if (customer.Sex == true)
            {
                dgvCustomerInfo.Rows[rowIndexCustomerInfo].Cells[1].Value = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                dgvCustomerInfo.Rows[rowIndexCustomerInfo].Cells[1].Value = "Female";
            }

            // Add favorite foof of customer to dgvFavouriteFoods
            int rowIndexFavouriteFood = dgvFavouriteFoods.Rows.Add();
            for (int i = 0; i < customer.FavouriteFoods.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < dgvFavouriteFoods.ColumnCount)
                {
                    dgvFavouriteFoods.Rows[rowIndexFavouriteFood].Cells[i].Value = customer.FavouriteFoods[i];
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customer1 = new Customer()
            {    
                Name ="Andrew", 
                Sex = true,
                FavouriteFoods = new List<string>(){"Pizza","Hot dog","Noodle","Chicken"
            }
            };
            Customer customer2 = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "Sandra",
                Sex = false,
                FavouriteFoods = new List<string>(){"Rice","Pork","Beef","Chicken"
            }
            };

            this.AddCustomer(customer1);
            this.AddCustomer(customer2);

        }
```

Note: The Customer class is required NOT be changed.

Comment: I assume this is homework ?  Will there always only be 2 customers ?  Does it just need to work ?

Comment: No, It's not home work. It imitates my project. I cannot find solution to sort the second datagridview, There will be many customers. When you call AddCustomer, datagridviews will have one more row.

Comment: Add customers to a list to create a list of customers when you sort the first grid rebind the second using the list sorted by your food sort.

Comment: But values of dgvFavouriteFoods are from List<string> FavouriteFoods of Customer. These values are not properties of Customer. How can I rebind the dgvCustomerInfo?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 class and one List:

```
private List<Customer> _myCustomers = new List<Customer>();

public class Customer
{
    /// <summary>  
    /// Name of customer  
    /// </summary>  
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>  
    /// Sex of customer  
    /// </summary>  
    public bool Sex { get; set; }

    /// <summary>  
    /// List of favourite foods
    /// </summary>  
    public List<FavouriteFood> FavouriteFoods { get; set; }
}

public class FavouriteFood {
    public FavouriteFood() { }
    public FavouriteFood(string _food) { this.Food = _food; }
    public string Food { get; set; }
}
```

FormLoad:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dgvCustomerInfo grid Mouse Up Event:
        this.dgvCustomerInfo.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.dgvCustomerInfo_MouseUp);

        Customer customer1 = new Customer()
        {
            Name = "Andrew",
            Sex = true,
            FavouriteFoods = new List<FavouriteFood>(){
                new FavouriteFood("Pizza"),
                new FavouriteFood("Hot dog"),
                new FavouriteFood("Noodle"),
                new FavouriteFood("Chicken")
        }
        };
        Customer customer2 = new Customer()
        {
            Name = "Sandra",
            Sex = false,
            FavouriteFoods = new List<FavouriteFood>()
            {
                new FavouriteFood("Rice"),
                new FavouriteFood("Pork"),
                new FavouriteFood("Beef"),
                new FavouriteFood("Chicken")
            }
        };

        _myCustomers.Add(customer1);
        _myCustomers.Add(customer2);

        dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = _myCustomers;
    }
```

Last: Mouse Up Event:

```
private void dgvCustomerInfo_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer _selected = (Customer)dgvCustomerInfo.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        dgvFavouriteFoods.DataSource = _selected.FavouriteFoods;
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do it without changing Customer class?

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for your help. Your code doesn't work as I expected. The favourite foods displayed in a column when click header of dgvCustomerInfo. I want the dgvCustomerInfo displays each row with corresponding row of dgvFavouriteFood when I click  header of dgvFavouriteFood.